# Axios giving 404 error, not inserting into database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express, axios

I basically created a simple UI using React and from there, I am taking user input in a form and sending it to my backend using axios.
Here is the frontend code:

```
import {useState} from "react";
import Axios from "axios"
function App() {

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("");
  const [position, setPosition] = useState("");
  const [wage, setWage] = useState(0);


  const addEmployee =()=>{
    console.log(name)
    Axios.post('http://localhost:6667/create', {name:name, age:age, country:country, position:position, wage:wage,})
    .then(()=>{
      console.log("Success from frontend")
    })

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
  <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onChange={(event)=>{setName(event.target.value)}}></input>

  <label htmlFor="Age">Age</label>
  <input type="text" id="Age" name="Age"  onChange={(event)=>{setAge(event.target.value)}}></input>

  <label htmlFor="Country">Country</label>
  <input type="text" id="Country" name="Country" onChange={(event)=>{setCountry(event.target.value)}}></input>

  <label htmlFor="Position">Position</label>
  <input type="text" id="Position" name="Position" onChange={(event)=>{setPosition(event.target.value)}}></input>

  <label htmlFor="Wage">Wage</label>
  <input type="text" id="Wage" name="Wage" onChange={(event)=>{setWage(event.target.value)}}></input>
  
  <button onClick={addEmployee}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the code for the sever (index.js file):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    host:"localhost",
    password:"password",   //it could be '' or 'password'
    database:'employeesystem'
});


app.post("/create", (request, response)=>{

    const name = request.body.name  
    const age = request.body.age
    const country = request.body.country
    const position = request.body.position
    const wage = request.body.wage

    db.query("INSERT INTO employee (name, age, country, position, wage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [name, age,country, position, wage], (err, result)=>{
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{res.send("Values Inserted!")}
    });
});

app.listen(6667, ()=>{
    console.log("Connection to server established")
})
```

So, the form is sending data to the backend using Axios and in the index.js (backend file), I am using express to insert it into my database. I have already checked any database or table name mismatch and there is none.

As soon as I submit my form data using a button (which triggers the function containing axios code), I get this error:

[image]

I already tried changing the ports, killing them, making sure database queries and names are consistent, and even restarting my IDE but to no avail.

Some help would be appreciated a lot cus I'm tired now:/

So ok, I did a quick googling and found that some ports are reserved or unsafe. So I changed the port to 7889 and now I got this error.
[image]

Comment: Looks like your backend is being served on port 3307 but your frontend is trying to contact port 3000

Comment: Yes, I did that by accident, changed that and this is what I am getting, "UNSAFE PORT ERROR".

Comment: some **ports** are reserved for other ptotocole that's why it gives you **"UNSAFE PORT ERROR"**  . you can try on  **port 3001**

Comment: Tried it already, still giving CONNECTION REFUSED ERROR.

Comment: No changing the port just to get rid of  **"UNSAFE PORT ERROR"** not to fix your  real error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually I was kind of making a silly mistake. In the index.js file, instead of doing `result.send()`, I was doing `res.send()`

Here's the corrected block of code:

```
b.query("INSERT INTO employee (name, age, country, position, wage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [name, age,country, position, wage], (err, result)=>{
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{result.send("Values Inserted!")}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify port in createConnection,

Configure your applications run on safe ports,

Example,

- F/E - PORT - 30xx
- B/E - PORT - 50xx
- D/B - PORT - 3306

  ```
   const db = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: '',
   database: 'employeesystem',
   port: 3036
   });
   db.connect();
  ```

In package.json of your react application add `"proxy"` It will allow app to pretend it is making request from the same port of server,

```
{
 ..
 ..  
 "devDependencies": {
   ...
  },
"proxy": "http://localhost:5100"  //if server run on port 5100 or < 
}
```